# lalrpop produces error - unresolved import lexer

Tags: parsing, rust

I am trying out parser lalrpop with the following grammar:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

grammar;

pub Term: i32 = {
    <n:Num> => n,
    "(" <t:Term> ")" => t,
};

Num: i32 = <s:r"[0-9]+"> => i32::from_str(s).unwrap();
```

When I try to use this parser, I get the following error and many similar ones:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `self::__lalrpop_util::lexer`
  --> /home/martijn/rust/quadratic-equations-2d/target/debug/build/quadratic-equations-2d-3e9c9d94e3adc760/out/lang.rs:22:31
   |
22 |     use self::__lalrpop_util::lexer::Token;
   |                               ^^^^^ could not find `lexer` in `__lalrpop_util`
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable feature `lexer` with your dependency `lalrpop-util`. You should include it in your `Cargo.toml` like so:

```
[dependencies]
lalrpop-util = {version = "0.19", features = ["lexer"]}
```

See https://github.com/lalrpop/lalrpop/issues/538.